# How to get the indexes of visible rows from the table on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the indexes of all visible rows from the table when i scroll the page. I have more then 500 rows in the html table so on the page scroll i want to get the visible rows of the table.

```js
$("#mainDiv").scroll(function () {
    var rows = $(this).find('table tbody tr');
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop();
    var visibleIndex = 0;
    var height = 0;
    rows.each(function (index, item) {
        if (offset == 0) {
            height = 0;
            visibleIndex = 0
            return false;
        }
        height += $(this).height();
        if (height > offset) {
            visibleIndex = index + 1;
            height = 0;
            return false;
        }
    })
    console.log(visibleIndex);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainDiv" style="height:100px;width:100%;overflow-y: scroll">
<table> 
<thead>
<tr><th>A</th> 
<th>Heading</th> 
<th>Row</th> 
<th>Row1</th>
<th>Row2</th>
<th>Row3</th>
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr> 
<td>The first1</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second2</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first3</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second4</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first5</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second6</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first7</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second8</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first9</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second10</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first11</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second12</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first13</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second14</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first15</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second16</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first17</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second18</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> <td>The second</td> 
 <td>row of</td> 
 <td>table data</td> 
 <td>The first</td>
 <td>row of</td>
 <td>table data</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

Please give me some idea to get the visible rows on scroll.
I want to get the indexes of all visible rows from the table when i scroll the page. I have more then 500 rows in the html table so on the page scroll i want to get the visible rows of the table.

Comment: Try using Jquery offset method to get the offset of parent and then offset of each row. if the offset of the row is within the height of parent then it is visible otherwise not.